# ECM Documentum migration testing

Tags: database, testing, documentum

I am new to Documentum, and currently working on a migration project.  A legacy database is going to be migrated to the Documentum platform.  Any ideas on how to perform database testing between a legacy database and a Documentum database?

If somebody has DQL that is useful from a testing perspective, kindly share with me.

Comment: Might mean Enterprise Content Management, but my guess is @wytten is correct.

Comment: Are you moving a legacy Documentum database to a new installation, or are you moving legacy external content into Documentum itself?  Are  you referring to tabular data, or files?

Answer (score 5):

The Documentum platform from EMC is a CMS (or ECM) tool used for content management.  It uses an external database for storing metadata, but is not a database itself.  Documentum will store and manage the content for you and keep the links to the content store (and a bunch of other business policy information) in the database.  So to your question, if you wish to include external database tabel(s) inside Documentum tablespace for running DQL queries to use both Documentum object tables and the external table, you need to "register" them so that they become accessible to Documentum's API and DQL.  The register DQL syntax is:

```
REGISTER TABLE [owner_name.]table_name
(column_def {,column_def})
[[WITH] KEY (column_list)]
[SYNONYM [FOR] 'table_identification']
```

Note, the table should be at least selectable to the docbase owner - the credential of the database user that Documentum uses to connect to it's database.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "*migration to the Documentum platform from a legacy database*", am taking the assumption that the legacy database has unstructured data stored as blob type which you need to move to a more relevant content storage medium (*like Documentum*).

You need to ensure the following aspects in the Testing approach

- Ensure that all data is actually migrated (*sort of log maintained during migration to tally against actual database content metrics*). You can also cross-check against a taxonomy object count after migration - this is based on business understanding of the database data.
- Ensure that data integrity is maintained during migration (*checksum of blob data and migrated repository content*).
- If you are migrating versions - checks to validate proper version history.
- Ensure that metadata is migrated properly during migration.

Usually customers will be okay with a sampling based test for the last three items. Have done this in the past building a custom test harness to exercise these options.

Answer (score -1):

you can try our ECM Migration platform, with 50k objects for free.  With it you can build repositories by transferring content and folders, and security, etc from a prod to a test repository, or you can generate one by specifying the types and numbers of folders, files in the folders, etc.  You can also re-do an import without creating duplicates and also clean up the big nasty testing target folders that you end up with.

you can download it here :  http://move.qtility.com